# Hiding Columns: setting the Range

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, range, runtime-error

My intentions are to copy a portion of one ws to another for formatting and printing.

I am having trouble when it comes to hiding the unnecessary columns. The code below returns

Compile Error:     Wrong Number of Arguments or Invalid Property Assignment-------- 'solved

Runtime Error:1004
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

'shTarget.Range("Rngc")='application defined or object defined error'

```
Private Sub IWasRunning()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim shSource As Worksheet
Dim shTarget As Worksheet
Dim shHelper As Worksheet
Dim Rnga As Range
Dim Rngb As Range
Dim Rngc As Range

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="E:\DE Daily Production Plan\A. Production Plans\(B. 1 of 2) Current Production Plans\Blue Line Schedule.XLSX", ReadOnly:=True)
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="E:\DE Daily Production Plan\A. Production Plans\(B. 1 of 2) Current Production Plans\Schedule Assist.XLSM", ReadOnly:=True)
Set shSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Schedule")
Set shTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("DailyPrintable")
Set shHelper = wbTarget.Worksheets("Start")
Set Rnga = shHelper.Range("A1")
Set Rngb = shHelper.Range("B1")
                     
Set Rngc = shTarget.Range("A:B", "F:F", "H:L", "N:AD")

wbTarget.Names.Add Name:="SKE", RefersTo:=Rnga
wbTarget.Names.Add Name:="Daily", RefersTo:=Rngb

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Stations = Array("3", "8", "13", "18", "23", "28")
For i = 0 To UBound(Stations)
   
   With shTarget.Rows(Stations(i))
     shSource.Rows(Range("SKE") + 2 - i).Rows("1:" & Range("Daily")).Copy
      shTarget.Rows(Range("Daily") * i + ("3" + i)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End With
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

With shTarget.Rows(2).Rows("1:" & Range("Daily") * 8).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 24
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
With shTarget.Rows(2).Rows("1:" & Range("Daily") * 8).Columns.AutoFit
    shTarget.Columns(4).Columns.ColumnWidth = 25
    shTarget.Rows(2).Rows("1:" & Range("Daily") * 8).RowHeight = 25
    End With
                'error occurs below 
    With shTarget.Range("Rngc")      'shTarget.Range("Rngc")=<application defined or object defined error>
         .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `shTarget.Range("A:B, F:F, H:L, N:AD")`

Comment: ok, here we go:  Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: `Rngc` is a range so `With Rngc` not `With shTarget.Range("Rngc")`

Comment: Awesome! and thanks for not blurting this and the next issue of the "with" block out initially!

Comment: What are typical values in shHelper.Range("A1")  and shHelper.Range("B1")